# How to access asp.net website using IP Address on WS2008 IIS7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net

I'm in the process of migrating a few sites from WS2003/IIS6 to WS2008/IIS7.  Have been reading online material all day about WS2008 and IIS7.  Still don't feel any smarter.

I put a basic test asp.net website in wwwroot (default web site directory) just to see if it would work and it did.

I've setup my multiple sites following these instructions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753729.aspx.

I want to see if they are setup properly, so I was trying to view them at http:// ip_address/ virtual_directory_name as described here for WS2003/IIS6: http:// forums.asp.net/t/1041300.aspx but I just get 404 errors back from IIS. (I'm a new user, so I had to break these links to get this to post)

It seems like I remember always creating virtual directories in IIS6.  It's not clear to me whether you have to do this or if it's optional in IIS7 when creating a new site, so I tried it both ways, ie. creating a virtual directory under the new site or not creating the virtual directory.  In either case, I still get the 404 errors.

Is it possible to view multiple sites on IIS7 via IPaddress/?? and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host an unlimited number of sites and set the bindings that work for you.

If you have a dedicated IP, which I assume you do, just make sure that the Host Header field is blank.  Then it will catch all traffic for that IP.

There are 3 binding choices for each IIS binding: a) IP address, b) port, c) host header.  The port is the only required binding.  If you set the host header, then it will *only* work for that specific host header.  That's why if you want to use host headers, you'll usually need 2 for every domain.  One for www and one without the www.  However, for an IP test, just leave it off all together.

Virtual directories were common with WinXP which it only allows 1 site.  You don't need to worry about vdirs for multiple sites unless you have specific needs for vdirs, or if you want a single site and domain name with subfolders.  (i.e. http://something.yourdomain.com would be a new site, while http://yourdomain.com/something would be a new folder or vdir).

Comment: Thanks, Scott, for explaining this.  I am now able to do a successful ip test after removing the host headers as you suggested and just using http:// my_ip_address:port_number_in_bindings.  Thanks also for explaining the need for 2 for every domain if I use host headers.  I was planning on using host headers once I got the dns re-mapped from the old server, and I wouldn't have known to setup multiple host headers to cover www and not.